# Explain C++ code from Superpowered CrossExample for Android

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, superpowered

This code occurs in the [CrossExample](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/tree/master/Android/CrossExample/app/src/main/java/com/superpowered/crossexample) from [superpowered.com](http://superpowered.com):

```
static void playerEventCallbackA(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent event, void * __unused value) {
    if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess) {

        SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *playerA = *((SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer **)clientData);

        playerA->setBpm(126.0f);
        playerA->setFirstBeatMs(353);
        playerA->setPosition(playerA->firstBeatMs, false, false);
    };
}    

    playerA = new SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer(&playerA , playerEventCallbackA, samplerate, 0);

    playerA->open(path, fileAoffset, fileAlength);
```

Can anyone help me understand the first line inside the `if` statement?  In particular, how do I interpret the right hand side of the assignment?

`*((SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer **)clientData)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clientData` is passed as a `void pointer`. Later, it is casted to `pointer to pointer` of type `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer`. I suposse that `clientData` was of that type before passing it to the function, that's why the cast is needed. I don't know why this `void*` is used instead of `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer**`. Not good, but not rare.

A var named `playerA` is a pointer to an object of type `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer`. Dereferencing the pointer to pointer you get a pointer to a `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer` object, just the same type as `playerA`.

Note that `playerA`is declared only inside the if-block, its life ends there. There's another `playerA` outside the block, that must be declared before assigning it to anything.